# How to resolve failed assembly verification when installing assembly into SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server, clrstoredprocedure, rebex

I need to do SFTP from within a SQL Server context. I can do FTP with MS libraries, but they do not support SFTP.

So I downloaded Rebex, and put together a sample project, and tried to install it into SQL Server as a CLR stored procedure.

When doing this, SQL Server gives the following message:

> Msg 6218, Level 16, State 2, Line 3
>
> CREATE ASSEMBLY for assembly 'RebexTest' failed because assembly 'Rebex.Common' failed verification. Check if the referenced assemblies are up-to-date and trusted (for external_access    or unsafe) to execute in the database. CLR Verifier error messages if any will follow this message
>
> [ : Rebex.Security.Certificates.CertificateStore::Exists][mdToken=0x60003b0]
>   [offset 0x000000C7]    Method is not visible.

Is there a way to fix this so I can install it into SQL Server?

Comment: Not sure, but I think this might help: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mattn/archive/2008/04/22/writing-clr-stored-procedures.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, Rebex components can only be used in CLR procedures with the `PERMISSION_SET = UNSAFE` option. See detailed explanation on the [Rebex support forum](http://forum.rebex.net/questions/3937/sftp-from-a-sql-server-context-gives-error-message/3957).

Comment: Jan, thanks for looking into this for me.  It is appreciated.